# Remove consecutive spaces in RDD lines in Spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

My data set after a lot of programmatic clean up looks like this (showing partial data set here).

```
ABCD        A M@L                             79
BGDA        F D@L                             89
```

I'd like to convert this into the following for further Spark Dataframe operations

```
ABCD,A,M@L,79
BGDA,F,D@L,89


val reg = """/\s{2,}/"""
val cleanedRDD2 = cleanedRDD1.filter(x=> !reg.pattern.matcher(x).matches())
```

But this returns nothing. How do i find and replace empty strings with a delimiter?
Thanks!
rt

Comment: Remove the regex delimiters: `val reg = """\s{2,}"""` and you cannot use `.matches()` as it requires the full string match. Use `find()`.

Comment: Perhaps, what you want is much simpler, something like https://ideone.com/T8OSIC.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. That helped!

Comment: If you dont mind, can you pls explain the regex?

Comment: Glad it did, I added the answer. There is a link to the regex demo, too.

Comment: `filter` just returns the lines that match the regex. I don't think that's what you want.  You probably want `map` to return an RDD with the modified lines.

Comment: yes. I used a map function instead. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want to replace all the non-vertical whitespaces in your string data. I suggest using `replaceAll` (to replace all the occurrences of the texts that match the pattern)  with `[\t\p{Zs}]+` regex.

Here is just a [sample code](https://ideone.com/T8OSIC):

```
val s = "ABCD        A M@L                             79\nBGDA        F D@L                             89"
val reg = """[\t\p{Zs}]+"""
val cleanedRDD2 = s.replaceAll(reg, ",")
print(cleanedRDD2)
// =>  ABCD,A,M@L,79
//     BGDA,F,D@L,89
```

And here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aW8rU4/1). The `[\t\p{Zs}]+` matches 1 or more occurrences of a tab (`\t`) or any Unicode whitespace from the [Space Separator category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm).

To modify the contents of the RDD, just use `.map`:

```
newRDD = yourRDD.map(elt => elt.replaceAll("""[\t\p{Zs}]+""", ","))
```

Comment: I added some more details on the regex I used.

Comment: Your code doesn't use RDDs (and you can't use `replaceAll` on an entire RDD). `map` with a `replaceAll` for each line would work though

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul: Yes, I know, I just posted the regex that will do that with proper mapping. If you want you may post the whole solution.

Comment: I'll leave it to you. You have 90% of the full solution already

Comment: Ok, as far as I see, `.map(elt => elt.replaceAll("""[\t\p{Zs}]+""", ","))` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use directly on RDD

```
rdd_nopunc = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split()).filter(lambda x: x.replace("[,.!?:;]", ""))
```